# Angular 5 *ngIf directive behaving weird with the boolean variable from constructor

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular5

I am using the **Angular 5.2 version** in my project and it is doing very weird issue in the DEV region.

HTML Component Code looks like this :-

```
    <div [hidden]="!_isFlag">
        <div class="pt-2 row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" placeholder="Last Name">
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>                    
  </div>


   <div [hidden]="_isFlag">
        <div class="pt-2 row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pNum" placeholder="Given Number">
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
</div>
```

And component.ts file looks like this below. The _currUser is populated with the help of localStorage object, which is different for every logged-in user.

```
    public _isFlag: boolean = false;    

    constructor(){
            this._isFlag= (<boolean>_currUser.isFlag);
    }
```

For some reason, only the first block of html code is getting rendered ir-respective of the _isFlag value. The second block of HTML code never comes into visibility, even if it met the _isFlag value.

This is really weird.

Comment: what does _currUser.isFlag contain?

Comment: a boolean value true or false.

Comment: can you print _isFlag value in constructor after init and check what it prints?

Comment: In Which event please ?

Comment: in constructor after you initialize it.

Comment: In constructor it gives the correct value

Comment: instead of hidden try to use *ngIf directive.

Comment: please check my answer, try using OnInit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below.

Instead of assigning flag in constructor assign it in ngOnInit.

```
ngOnInit(){

this._isFlag= (<boolean>_currUser.isFlag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of isFlag is probably a string "true" of "false" instead of the value true or value; and if("false") is actually true because a string translates to a truthy value in javascript. Try this:

```
constructor(){
    this._isFlag= (_currUser.isFlag === 'true');
}
```